# suppose n is a natural number , prove equation $x^n+nx-1=0$ exist an unique real positive root $x_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, roots

suppose n is a natural number

prove :

equation $x^n+nx-1=0$ exist an unique real positive root $x_n$ ; and when $a>1$,$\sum_{n=1}^{\inf}x^a_n$ converges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you problem may add this $x$ domain,following I add $x>0$
$$f(x)=x^n+nx-1\Longrightarrow f'(x)=n(x^{n-1}+1)>0$$
and
$$f(0)=-1<0,f(\dfrac{1}{n})=\dfrac{1}{n^n}>0$$
so this equation has unique real postive..

and $$f(\dfrac{1}{n+1})=\left(\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)^n-\dfrac{1}{n+1}<0$$
so
$$\dfrac{1}{n+1}<x_{n}<\dfrac{1}{n}$$
so
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^a_{n},a>1$$converges

Comment: why $f′(x)=n(x^{n−1}+1)>0$?

Comment: @zane $D ( x^n + nx -1) = D ( x^n ) + D (nx)+D(-1)$

Comment: @zane. You are working in the real domain, $x>0$ would be enough.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici How can we know $x>0$?

Comment: you must add the domain

Comment: @VincenzoOliva I know how to derivative it . But I can't figure out why $n(x^{n−1}+1)>0$  can't $x$ be negative?

Comment: @math110 The question doesn't contain a domain . For all real number ?

Comment: if you question doesn't contain a domai $x>0$, this problem is wrong such $n=2$,it is clear $x^2+2x-1=0$ have $x<0$ real roots

Comment: @math110 thx. Maybe there are some printing mistakes on my exam paper .